# show file downloaded in KB in progress bar

Tags: android

I want create a progress bar.
I also want to show file downloaded/total file size. e.g. 12.23kb/10 mb.
Do i need to use text boxes around progress bar, or does progress bar provide inbuilt methods.

```
class showdownload{
ProgressBar progressbar = null;
setProgressBarProgress(String... progress)
{

  String kb = progress[0];
  String mb = progress[1];
  String percentage = Integer.toInt(progress[2]);
  progressbar.setProgress(percentage );

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this way:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/some_photo_from_gdansk_poland.jpg");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
return null;

}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
     Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
     mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the range of the progress bar to be the size of the download (eg. 10.000 Kb), and then set the progress in Kb. It should display exactly what you want.

I would recommend to use the ProgressDialog class.

Comment: range will be same as setMax. and it takes integers. I need to show text just above the progressbar 12.23kb/12 mb. Top left may be.

Comment: ProgressDialog will show text just below. For the text above the progress bar, indeed, you will need to create your own view that has a text view and a progress bar.